# T-SQL Two Where Clauses on same column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, where-clause

In SQL Server 2008, I have below Table Sample.

```
Name   Num
----------
John    20
John    30
Peter   10
Peter   20
Peter   30
Marry   20
Marry   30
Mike    10
Mike    20
Mike    30
Phil    10
Phil    30
```

I want records having Num = 10 and Num = 20. The query will return

```
Name   Num
----------
Peter   10
Peter   20
Mike    10
Mike    20
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
SELECT Name, Num
FROM tbl
WHERE Name IN (
    SELECT Name FROM tbl
    WHERE Num IN (10, 20)
    GROUP BY Name 
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 -- Must have all items in the set of 2
)
AND Num IN (10, 20) -- still need to restrict, since the set is not maximal
```

But there are other ways to skin the "set of items with all the following attributes" cat.

Comment: +1 @user219628 some other options here http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/

Comment: @Martin - That is an excellent article.  Thanks for linking it.

Answer (score 1):

Either of these will produce the output you want:

```
SELECT * FROM Sample WHERE Num IN (10, 20)
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM Sample WHERE Num = 10 OR Num = 20
```

**EDIT**: Sorry, that seems like it's not really what you wanted. I believe this will work, but it's not very elegant:

```
SELECT * FROM Sample
WHERE Name IN (SELECT Name FROM Sample WHERE Num = 10)
  AND Name IN (SELECT Name FROM Sample WHERE Num = 20)
```

There is probably a better solution. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: He's asking for Names that have at least one row with 10, and at least one row with 20.

Comment: The edited version will still show Peter 30, which isn't what the OP wanted.

Comment: Your current solution returns rows for Peter and Mike where Num is not 10 or 20.

Comment: Yes, that was mentioned by Cade Roux, whose answer I up-voted. I believe his is the right approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
SELECT Name, Num
FROM MyTableSample s
WHERE Num in (10, 20)
    AND EXISTS
        (
        SELECT Name
        FROM MyTableSample s2
        WHERE s.name = s2.Name
            AND s.Num <> s2.Num
            AND s2.Num in (10, 20)
        )
```

Comment: Need to watch out that this won't scale to the case of three items in the list because of the use of <> to find the "other" entry.  In the case of more than 2 items, there will be false "other"s.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
SELECT *
  FROM    (SELECT Name, Num FROM Sample WHERE Num = 10) A,
                    (SELECT Name, Num FROM Sample WHERE Num = 20) B
where A.nAME = B.nAME
```